# Quartz Scheduler worker threads not running jobs even with huge number of jobs in queue

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

We have 30 worker threads in quartz scheduler, and there are 104k jobs in the queue (they were piled up since quartz was not processing fast enough and the lots of bulk jobs were submitted). As you can see in the thread dump, most of these threads are just waiting without working. Why are these worker threads not running all those jobs which are in the queue missing the fire time?

Could there be any bottlenecks before the jobs are distributed to the workers? We see only a few jobs running at any time instead of upto 30 jobs at once.

I should note that this happens irrespective of only one scheduler process or many.

Any pointers to find why many (at most 30) jobs are not getting picked up and executed at once would be really appreciated.

Quartz version: 2.1.3 (with Oracle JDBC jobstore)

**Config File**

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = ****_SCHEDULER
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 30
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5


#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_


#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = *****
#org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = *****
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 10
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery=select 0 from dual

#============================================================================
# Configured to batch trigger acquisition
#============================================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = false
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount = 30
org.quartz.jobStore.acquireTriggersWithinLock = true
~
```

**Thread Dump**
[image: Quartz Threads]

I see the QuartzSchedulerThread (i assume is like manager thread?) and MisfireHandler threads are always running with same stacktrace (except for locked monitor id).

**Stacktrace for QuartzSchedulerThread**

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) 
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129) 
at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:300) 
at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106) 
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315) 
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260) 
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185) 
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1199) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628) 
- locked [0x00000007f5d0fd30] (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493) 
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:91) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:115) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3803) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggersFired(JobStoreSupport.java:2893) 
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:326)
```

**Stacktrace for MisfireHandler thread:**

```html
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) 
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129) 
at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:300) 
at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106) 
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315) 
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260) 
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185) 
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1199) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628) 
- locked [0x00000007f58c8010] (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection) 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493) 
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.hasMisfiredTriggersInState(StdJDBCDelegate.java:379) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:946) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3187) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3946) 
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3967)
```

Comment: I don't know much about Quartz scheduler, but how are the jobs submitted to the pool ? Is it possible that the scheduler thread is the one distributing the tasks over, but it is currently locked on IO (`java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0`) and therefore cannot tell the workers what to do ?

Comment: The jobs are submitted by a different java process which only submit the job and not execute them. It could be possible that the SchedulerThread is busy on IO (read the jobs?) and not distributing them like you said. I am not sure how to find out what exactly is the bottleneck. I cannot reproduce it in my local and thread dumps are not helping much. :(

Comment: Do you mind sharing some of the code ?

Comment: How is Quartz setup?  Inside Tomcat?  As a standalone?  Also, at 30 threads is there any chance you've exceeded the capacity of the server/host?  Maybe drop to 10 threads and push 30 jobs thru and monitor the thread dump to see if they process thru.  Finally, what version of Quartz are you using?  I've been working a Spring/Tomcat/Quartz related issue involving Quartz 1.8.6 that freezes Tomcat.

Comment: @Dici The code I have are classes that implements Job interface of Quartz. It would not help here anyway. It is more of my configuration issue or bug on quartz. Unfortunately, I cannot share the code for my job (company policy)

Comment: @lincolnadym The server is still at 25-54% cpu. The issue seems to be bottleneck on the thread reading/distributing the jobs. We saw a lots of DB contention with the query run by the quartz to fetch the jobs. Had some luck with restarting only one standalone instance of quartz for now. Still trying to figure out if multiple instances of quartz are causing this or some other issue with DB.

Comment: @wildnux Did you ever find a solution for the issue? I'm having a similar thing with TIMED_WAITING threads while Jobs are waiting.

Comment: @dajoropo although i could not pinpoint the specific cause, running only one instance helped a lot. Also, setting `org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow` to 2-3 minutes also sped up the processing of huge number of jobs scheduled around same time.

Comment: @wildnux Thanks for the response! In my case at the end we've found a bug in Oracle 11 that was making one select query to hang forever without timeout. Because of that the thread was active waiting the result of the query without doing anything else. So at the end it wasn't a Quartz problem at all.